# Confusion with Edwards's Proof of Inverse Mapping Theorem: The convergent sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, induction

This question arose while working through the proof of the inverse
mapping theorem (Theorem III 3.3) in C.H. Edwards, Jr.'s Advanced
Calculus of Several Variables.

Edit to add definitions:
$f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ mapping in a neighborhood of the point $a$. $T=df_{a}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the differential of $f$ at $a$.

The follow are established in the text

$g_{0}(y)=a$

$\tau_{a}(x)=x+a$

$T\circ\tau_{a}^{-1}\circ g_{k+1}(y)=T\circ\tau_{a}^{-1}\circ g_{k}(y)-[f(g_{k}(y))-y]$.

Edwards instructs the student to apply $\tau_{a}\circ T^{-1}$
to both sides of this expression. What I get is

$g_{k+1}(y)=g_{k}(y)-\tau_{a}\circ T^{-1}[f(g_{k}(y))-y]$

$g_{k+1}(y)=g_{k}(y)-T^{-1}[f(g_{k}(y))-y]-a$.

Edwards gives the generic induction step as

$g_{k+1}(y)=g_{k}(y)-T^{-1}[f(g_{k}(y))-y]$.

Now, according to my result the first induction step is

$g_{1}(y)=g_{0}(y)-T^{-1}[f(g_{0}(y))-y]-a$

$=a-T^{-1}[f(a)-y]-a$

$=-T^{-1}[f(a)-y]$

So the $-a$ is canceled. But I don't see how that would be inherited
in subsequent steps. For example,

$g_{2}(y)=-T^{-1}[f(-T^{-1}[f(a)-y])-y]-a$

seems to be the obvious next term.

Where is the error?

Comment: I now believe Edwards is wrong.  That would mean that the theorem is stated incorrectly in the book.  I would like independent verification of this before I accept it as an answer.

Comment: Could you, for those of us who don't have the book [nor convenient access to it], add a few details about what is what? I suppose $f$ is the continuously differentiable function whose (local) inverse shall be constructed, and $T$ is probably multiplication with the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at some point? What is $a$ exactly?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I added some definitions to the original post.  I had omitted them because I believe they are not relevant to the derivation.  It appears to be purely an issue of symbol manipulation.  The entire proof is over two pages long, and rather complicated.  Perhaps I can find a way to photocopy it, and make it available online.  Thanks for taking an interest in my question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a mistake in the book. The point is that the translation $\tau_a$ is *not* linear, but you treated it as if it were.

We don't have

$$\tau_a\bigl(\tau_a^{-1}(g_k(y) - [f(g_k(y))-y]\bigr) = \tau_a\bigl(\tau_a^{-1}(g_k(y))\bigr) - \tau_a[f(g_k(y))-y]$$

but

$$\tau_a\bigl(\tau_a^{-1}(g_k(y) - [f(g_k(y))-y]\bigr) = \tau_a\bigl(\tau_a^{-1}(g_k(y))\bigr) - [f(g_k(y))-y].$$

That error would be easier to avoid if instead of $T\circ \tau_a^{-1}\circ g_k(y)$ one wrote

$$T\bigl(g_k(y) - a\bigr).$$

Then it's easy to see that

$$T\bigl(g_{k+1}(y) - a\bigr) = T\bigl(g_k(y) - a\bigr) - [f(g_k(y)) - y]$$

is transformed first to

$$\bigl(g_{k+1}(y) - a\bigr) = \bigl(g_k(y) - a\bigr) - T^{-1}[f(g_k(y))-y]$$

and then to

$$g_{k+1}(y) = g_k(y) - T^{-1}[f(g_k(y))-y].$$

Answer (score 0):

WRONG:I am convinced the book is wrong.  The terms of the series should be as I have shown them.

As Daniel Fischer so generously pointed out, I was treating $\tau_{a}(x)=x+a$ as a linear function.  Actually, my mind was treating $\circ$ as a distributive operator.

$\tau_{a}(x)=x+a$

$\tau_{a}(\xi x)+\tau_{a}(\sigma y)=\xi x+\sigma y+2a$

$\tau_{a}(\xi x+\sigma y)=\xi x+\sigma y+a\ne\tau_{a}(\xi x)+\tau_{a}(\sigma y)$

If $x_{n+1}=\phi(x_{n})$ then

$\tau_{a}(x_{n+1})=\tau_{a}(\phi(x_{n}))$

$=x_{n+1}+a=\phi(x_{n})+a$

So applying $\tau_{a}$ to both sides of the induction rule equation
has a null effect.